# Retornar linhas do txt para JSON no PHP

Tags: php, json

Amigos, me ajudem com a minha aula? Estou fazendo curso de programação e estou apanhando com o JSON.

Tenho um arquivo de texto (.txt) com 5 linhas contendo os nomes dos alunos da minha sala dai preciso retoná-las com `JSON` e depois trabalhá-las individualmente no PHP.

Arquivo alunos.txt

```
João Gilberto
Pedro Simões
Fernando Leal
Jaqueline Silveira
Luana Godói
```

O professor disse que preciso fazer isso com o `json_encode` e depois usar o comando `for` para retornar, mas sinceramente ainda não consegui trabalhar elas individualmente.

```
$linhas = explode("\n", $$txt); //Separo cada linha do arquivo txt

$nomes = array();   
for($i = 0; $i <= count($linhas)-1; $i++) { //Percorro cada uma das linhas

    $nome = $linhas[$i];

}

echo json_encode($nome);
```

Sei que estou fazendo algo muito errado, pois está retonando null...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer desta maneira:

```
<?php
   $arquivo = file("alunos.txt");
   $json = json_encode($arquivo);
```

A função `file("alunos.txt")` será para pegar cada linha do arquivo e separá-las dentro de um `array` para depois passar para o `JSON` com `json_encode()`.

Você também pode tentar desta maneira aqui:

```
<?php
    $arquivo = file_get_contents("alunos.txt")
    $arquivo = explode("\n", $arquivo);

    $json = json_encode($arquivo);
```

mas recomendo a maneira acima por ser menor e por ter a mesma funcionalidade, busque sempre a maneira mais simples de resolver algum problema.

Comment: Que perfeito! Muito fácil! Só para esclarecimento: e caso eu pegasse o conteúdo via file_get_contents e utilizasse o for como eu sugeri lá em cima? O jeito que você fez já me ajuda com a tarefa, sim. Mas pensando me restou a dúvida. Mas já agradeço enormemente Ângelo!

Comment: o for não é preciso no seu código, apenas o explode e o json_encode já servem